# How to copy entire lines between buffers in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I would like to copy an entire line from buffer A -to-> buffer B.

The same way you would do it in an Ediff session. 
That you just press A or B and the entireline is copied.

However I'm not in an ediff because both files are different.

Is there a fast way to do it?

Or will a keyboard macro be the best option??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A keyboard macro is definitely the best option here unless you're interested in learning emacs-lisp.

Here is <kbd>C-h l</kbd> lossage from recording this macro

> C-x ( C-a C-SPC C-n M-w C-x o C-a C-y C-u - 1 C-x o C-x )

Here is the macro dumped as text (`edit-last-kbd-macro`)

```
;; Keyboard Macro Editor.  Press C-c C-c to finish; press C-x k RET to cancel.
;; Original keys: C-a C-SPC C-n M-w C-x o C-a C-y C-u -1 C-x o

Command: last-kbd-macro
Key: none

Macro:

C-a         ;; le::beginning-of-line
C-SPC           ;; set-mark-command
C-n         ;; next-line
M-w         ;; le::kill-ring-save
C-x o           ;; other-window
C-a         ;; le::beginning-of-line
C-y         ;; yank
C-u -1 C-x o        ;; other-window
```

Here is the code to bind the macro to a key in your init file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") [?\C-a ?\C-  ?\C-n ?\M-w ?\C-x ?o ?\C-a ?\C-y ?\C-u ?- ?1 ?\C-x ?o])
```

Comment: Also, function `append-to-buffer` may be useful. It can be used instead of sequence `other-window`, `kill-ring-save` and `yank`.

Comment: Yep that's a simpler sequence, and it doesn't take up a slot in your kill-ring.  The above isn't optimized, I would record quite a few ad hoc macros as I edit files, and almost never save them, so efficiency isn't an issue for me.